# How to read property of external application.properties from log4j2-spring.xml?

Tags: spring-boot, log4j2

I am developing a spring boot application. In log4j2-spring.xml, I used a property of application.properties to get the log file location. If I run the application keeping application.properties in jar, it creates log in my expected directory. This is inside of the jar then:

[image]

directory structure is like this:

[image]

And after running the app, log is in my expected directory:

[image]

But I need to keep application.properties file outside of jar. I am keeping log4j2-spring.xml still in jar. Then inside of jar, it looks like this:

[image]

And directory structure is:

[image]

My expectation is, this time log will be in **logs** directory too. But instead, after running the app, it is creating log in **jar** directory. Then it looks like this:

[image]

My application.properties file is:

```
#server
server.servlet.context-path=
server.tomcat.basedir=/home/ubuntu/test
server.address=localhost
server.port=8080
server.shutdown=graceful
spring.lifecycle.timeout-per-shutdown-phase=30s
server.servlet.session.timeout=120m

#log
logging.config=classpath:log4j2-spring.xml
logging.level.root=DEBUG
```

And log4j2-spring.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <Properties>
        <Property name="basedir">${bundle:application:server.tomcat.basedir}</Property>
    </Properties>

    <Appenders>
        <Console name="console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout
                    pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{2}:%L - %msg%n" />
        </Console>

        <RollingFile name="CATALINA-FILE" fileName="${basedir}/logs/catalina.log"
                     filePattern="${basedir}/logs/archived/catalina_%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log.gz">
            <PatternLayout>
                <Pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{20}:%L - %msg%n</Pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1"/>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="1 GB" />
            </Policies>
        </RollingFile>
    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>
        <root level="debug">
            <appender-ref ref="CATALINA-FILE"/>
            <appender-ref ref="console"/>
        </root>
    </Loggers>
</configuration>
```

If I replace this:

```
<Properties>
    <Property name="basedir">${bundle:application:server.tomcat.basedir}</Property>
</Properties>
```

with this:

```
<Properties>
    <Property name="basedir">/home/ubuntu/test</Property>
</Properties>
```

then log file also is created in my expected one. But I need to take this directory from application.properties, so that I need to change in only one file in future(if needed). How to do this?

Comment: Would you please try `<Property name="basedir">${server.tomcat.basedir}</Property>`

Comment: this change creates a directory in jar directory named ${server.tomcat.basedir} after running the application. @AtaurRahmanMunna vai

Comment: I guess your `basedir` variable doesn't recognized by the system,don't know why. Would you try using environment variable by setting a value like "`BASE_DIR=/path/to/logs`" and ensured by running the command `echo $BASE_DIR`?

Comment: basedir is known, if I keep the application.properties in jar. otherwise, it is not known. I tried with setting environment variable. It works. Though this design has issue, but need to go through that. @AtaurRahmanMunna vai